# What is the right way to convert from Double to Fixed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have some code that uses [`Centi`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Centi) for its currency type. It receives `Double`s from an Excel spreadsheet using the [xlsx](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xlsx) package. I want to convert these `Double`s into `Centi`s correctly. I have tried using `realToFrac`, and for the most part it works, but occasionally it's out by a cent:

```hs
λ realToFrac (-1372.92 :: Double) :: Centi
-1372.93
```

I can guess that the problem is in the binary representation of that decimal number not being exact, and that I shouldn't be using `Double` to represent currency in the first place, but I don't have control of that part. So what is a fail-safe way of doing the conversion?

Comment: Irks... that's really weird behaviour, and it's not the fault of `Double` but of `Fixed`. It turns out the `Fractional Fixed` instance always rounds towards -∞. _Very questionable_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout is it a bug, do you think?

Comment: I don't think it's strictly speaking a bug. This does seem to be behaviour by intention (so that `/` behaves as `div`?)... _why_ the authors designed it this way, I can't say. My personal opinion is that fixed-precision just generally doesn't make sense – but clearly many people disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best way but one is to [`round`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round) to the closest integer after adjusting for the desired precision:

```
floatToCenti :: Double -> Centi
floatToCenti = floatToFixed

floatToFixed :: HasResolution a => Double -> Fixed a
floatToFixed x = y where
  y = MkFixed (round (fromInteger (resolution y) * x))
  -- reusing y as the dummy argument of resolution
```